# c# .NET CORE adding image with transparency to existing PDF using ITextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, .net-core

My goal is to add company logo to every page of an existing pdf(not watermark).

Due to pdf file and logo specifics, I can only place the logo on top of the pdf content(not underneath) and the logo has to support transparency.

One more limitation is I have to use .NET Core.

Posting this with an answer, because I could not find a clear solution.
Suggestions/corrections/improvements are welcome.

Hope someone finds this useful.

Comment: iText 7 supports .NET Core. I suggest that you use iText 7 for .NET Core, and not the old iTextSharp.

Comment: iText7 can be used either under AGPL terms or via purchase, neither of which is possible for my situation. But thank you for pointing it out, I will change my answer

Comment: If you can't use the AGPL version because you want to use iText in a commercial context, you can't use the version you are currently using either. See [Can iText 2.1.7 / iTextSharp 4.1.6 or earlier be used commercially?](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/versions-older-than-5)

Comment: Your attitude "I want to use iText in a commercial context, but I don't want to purchase a commercial license" (or "my customer doesn't want to purchase a commercial license") is part of a race to the bottom for developers. If you want the job of developer to be something you can be proud of, you shouldn't participate in this downward spiral. Please read [the Realities of Being a FOSS Maintainer](https://caddy.community/t/the-realities-of-being-a-foss-maintainer/2728) and hopefully you'll understand my reaction.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie He can use that library just fine. He just needs to open source it since he uses modified version of the library that is under LGPL. It's not up to you, me or anyone to be the judge for it. He is not required to use the latest version..

Comment: @sotn Your comment would be correct if there weren't any IP issues with that modified version that is under LGPL. Because of those issues those versions can't be used under the AGPL. The code won't pass a technical due diligence.

Comment: I got you. If it was the OP that modified it for .Net Core compatible, then he would be able to use it but not with the current conditions.

Answer (score 2):

The newest iTextSharp library to support .NET Core is [iText7](https://itextpdf.com/) however I cannot use it legitemately; neither making my code open source, nor purchasing the licence is an option for me. Therefore I use old, third party library:

```
Install-Package iTextSharp.LGPLv2.Core
```

Latest version, the one I'm using, at the time of this post is 1.3.2

Following usings are required

```
using System;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
```

To acheve image transparency in pdf, image has to be opened in a correct format

```
var preImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(imagePath);
var image = Image.GetInstance(preImage, ImageFormat.Png);
```

When adding the image, it is also important to not select the image to be inline

```
canvas.AddImage(image);//do not put .AddImage(image, true);
```

Here is all the code

```
var imagePath = "logo.png";
var pdfPath = "edit_this.pdf";

//load pdf file
var pdfBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(pdfPath);
var oldFile = new PdfReader(pdfBytes);

//load image
var preImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(imagePath);
var image = Image.GetInstance(preImage, ImageFormat.Png);
preImage.Dispose();

//optional: if image is wider than the page, scale down the image to fit the page
var sizeWithRotation = oldFile.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1);
if (image.Width > sizeWithRotation.Width)
    image.ScalePercent(sizeWithRotation.Width / image.Width * 100);

//set image position in top left corner
//in pdf files, cooridinates start in the left bottom corner
image.SetAbsolutePosition(0, sizeWithRotation.Height - image.ScaledHeight);

//in production, I use MemoryStream
//I put FileStream here to test the code in console application
using (var newFileStream = new FileStream("with_logo.pdf", FileMode.Create))
{
    //setup PdfStamper
    var stamper = new PdfStamper(oldFile, newFileStream);

    //iterate through the pages in the original file
    for (var i = 1; i <= oldFile.NumberOfPages; i++)
    {
        //get canvas for current page
        var canvas = stamper.GetOverContent(i);
        //add image with pre-set position and size
        canvas.AddImage(image);
    }

    stamper.Close();
}
```

This code works with local files.
In my (real world) case, I receive pdf files as Base64 string, add a logo from local storage, convert it back to Base64 string and output it on a web-page.

I open the image as PNG forcefully(hardcoded) because I control what extension does the logo have. If necessary you can dynamicaly set the image format.

Comment: What a lame idea of the people who published `iTextSharp.LGPLv2.Core` to base their "latest" version on an official iText version that is 9 years old. I wonder why they didn't chose to create a C# .NET Core version on the [iText 7 developer platform](https://itextpdf.com/itext-developer-platform). That way, they would be backed by iText Group. Now they are on their own, and they can't benefit from the PDF knowhow accumulated in iText Group.

Comment: The latest .NET Core version of iText is iText 7.0.5: https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext7/7.0.5 (not iTextSharp.LGPLv2.Core 1.3.2 as you claim in your answer).

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. Changed the answer to use PdfStamper. Less code, easyer to read. pretty sweet :)

Comment: If you write that you cannot use software X in a legitimate way, then you cannot use software X. Stack Overflow is not a place where you can discuss illegitimate use of software.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse What's illegitimate here? I think that OP used wrong keyword there and meant he can't buy a license. itextsharp versions below 4.1.6 are not under AGPL but LGPL and since he uses a modified version of the library (.NET Core ported one of the LGPL version), he is required to open source his application. Can you prove (or supposed to prove really?) that he did not open source his application or just accusing him for asking questions about the old versions? Because he can...

Comment: @sotn Your assumption that versions predating version 5 under the LGPL is wrong. See https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/435/what-happens-if-stolen-software-is-published-as-open-source/437#437 and  https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/versions-older-than-5 for clarification.