# Image transparency in PDF using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext, pdf-generation

I have an incoming jpg file, that I can set a colour to transparent. When I add the image to another image, this works perfectly.

I am trying to add the same image to a PDF using iTextSharp, but I cannot get the transparency to work.

I have tried two ways, but neither is working. The first way was to open the image in a Bitmap, set transparency, then use that Bitmap object in the PDF. The second way (shown here) was saving the Bitmap to disk and opening the file into the iTextSharp image.

```
                    using (Bitmap b = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/IncomingData/" + ImageFileName))))
                    {
                        b.MakeTransparent(Color.White);
                        b.Save(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/IncomingData/" + GuidFileName), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                        ImageFileName = GuidFileName;

                        iTextSharp.text.Image savedImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Image.FromFile(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/IncomingData/" + GuidFileName)), iTextSharp.text.Color.WHITE);

                        savedImage.SetAbsolutePosition(Convert.ToSingle(x + 1.0), Convert.ToSingle(imageY + 12) - Convert.ToSingle(h));
                        savedImage.ScaleToFit(Convert.ToSingle(w), Convert.ToSingle(h));
                        contentByte.AddImage(savedImage, true);
                    }
```

I have seen that there is a Transparency option...

```
savedImage.Transparency = ???
```

but I don't know what to put in the values. I can't find anything on my searches.

Comment: Something here does not make sense because JPEG does not support transparency. How do you “add the image to another image”?

Comment: JPEG do not support transparency, but give it a go. It will become transparent, which you can then save out as .png. That is what MakeTransparent does.

In this question, I am not adding to another image, I am adding to a PDF.  To add the transparent "jpg" to another image...

 Bitmap b = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/IncomingData/" + GuidFileName));

                        b.MakeTransparent(Color.White);

                    graphics.DrawImage(b, x, y - 10, newWidth, newHeight);

Comment: how did you check whether either of your two attempts worked or not?

Comment: By running it and checking the output files... also by hitting my breakpoints to ensure it actually ran the code. Also, as I am creating a transparent .png file (in the code above), I have the file to hand and the png is definitely transparent. It is just not transparent when put onto the PDF.

Comment: FYI. I changed this... iTextSharp.text.Image savedImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Image.FromFile(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/IncomingData/" + GuidFileName)), iTextSharp.text.Color.WHITE);
to this...
iTextSharp.text.Image savedImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/IncomingData/" + GuidFileName));
so that it is taking direct from the file instead of loading into an image object first. Now, my PDF is showing a BLACK background where it should be transparent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer, eventually.

I saw this... and originally I was looking for .Transparency to find the transparency settings. I didn't see it.
[c# .NET CORE adding image with transparency to existing PDF using ITextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47073013/c-sharp-net-core-adding-image-with-transparency-to-existing-pdf-using-itextshar)

My code is now...

```
                    using (Bitmap b = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/IncomingData/" + ImageFileName))))
                    {
                        b.MakeTransparent(Color.White);

                        iTextSharp.text.Image savedImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(b, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

                        savedImage.SetAbsolutePosition(Convert.ToSingle(x + 1.0), Convert.ToSingle(imageY + 12) - Convert.ToSingle(h));
                        savedImage.ScaleToFit(Convert.ToSingle(w), Convert.ToSingle(h));

                        contentByte.AddImage(savedImage);
                    }
```

Note that the contentByte.AddImage has the boolean removed.

Comment: Ah, that Boolean did not catch my eye in your question. If you wonder what it is for: if `true`, the image is embedded inline in the content stream. Otherwise, it is added as a resource and merely referenced from the contentstream. Transparency requires a transparency mask to be generated as a separate resource. Because of this, probably, the transparency was lost in your tests.