# Color with transparency in iText 7.1.4

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext, itext7

Can I use a color with transparency in my programm, and I want to use this color in my PDF file. I create my pdf with iText 7.1.4, and I don't know how to set transpanrent to type of `DeviceRgb`:

```
public static DeviceRgb ToDeviceRgb(this System.Windows.Media.Color color) =>
    new DeviceRgb(color.R, color.G, color.B);
```

Is it possible to use color with transparency in iText7?

**UPDATED:**

I tried to do as **Uladzimir Asipchuk** told me, but I don't see any result:
[image]

A template of the product card I can edit in my program(margin, padding, colors, fonts etc..).
When setting up a template, some colors may have a alpha cannel(transparent), and I want to see this transparent factor in my PDF document.
So, as **Uladzimir Asipchuk** advised me, I pass the opacity level to the second parameter in the SetBackgroundColor method:

```
public override Table CreateTemplate(Product product)
{
    if(product == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(product));

    // Create a table of the product card
    var productTable = new Table(new UnitValue[] { UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(40), UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(60) })
        .SetWidth(UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(100))
        .SetBackgroundColor(Settings.BackgroundColor.ToDeviceRgb(), 0.3f) // Here!!
        .SetMarginBottom(10)
        .SetKeepTogether(true);

    // Here we create a cell of the header, 
    // image, description, notes, prices of out product card

    return productTable;
}
```

And how can you see on the screenshot, I don't have a color transparent equal 0.3f

Comment: There isn't anything in those methods that supports Alpha; which is typically the transparency part of the setting. Perhaps this question & answer can help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47600327/image-transparency-in-pdf-using-itextsharp

Comment: For regular drawing (text, vector graphics) you usually set transparency by means of an `ExtGState` or an smask.

Comment: @mkl, I mainly use tables with cells in my PDF document. I want to set transparent on cells background, but I can't

Comment: Then you can simply set transparency to the desired value (or use a different rendering mode which sometimes results in something better) while drawing the background. That being said why do you need the cell background to be transparent? Is it applied onto a general page background which must shimmer through?

Comment: Oh. I want are of what Uladzimir posted add answer. So that's the easiest way to create transparency. Nonetheless I wonder why you need transparency in the background...

Comment: @Darren I've tested the next snippet (which was created based on your code) both in Java and C# (with 7.1.4 and the latest versions) and could't reproduce the issue.
https://pastebin.com/qsq0Xudx

Please could you try the code above and tell me whether you get a satisfactory result or not?

Comment: @UladzimirAsipchuk, Everything worked out. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iText supports transparent colors for backgrounds. Please look at the samples there: https://github.com/itext/itext7/tree/develop/layout/src/test/resources/com/itextpdf/layout/OpacityTest

For example, with the next snippet I can get satisfactory results:

```
    Table table = new Table(1);
    table.addCell(new Cell().setBackgroundColor(new DeviceRgb(200, 100, 50), 1f).add(new Paragraph("Cell with Opacoty 1")));
    table.addCell(new Cell().setBackgroundColor(new DeviceRgb(200, 100, 50), 0.5f).add(new Paragraph("Cell with Opacoty 0.5")));
    table.addCell(new Cell().setBackgroundColor(new DeviceRgb(200, 100, 50), 0.1f).add(new Paragraph("Cell with Opacoty 0.1")));
    doc.add(table);
```

[image]